# Why don't std template functions need to be qualified?

Tags: c++, templates

When messing around with the global namespace qualifier, I noticed that you don't actually need `std::` for template functions, like `sort` and `accumulate` for example. Therefore if you have a function that shares a name with one of them, you would do something like `::sort` to remove ambiguity. However, I did not know you could call those functions without saying `std::`. Why is this so?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup -- And it doesn't just apply to namespace std.

Comment: The same reason that `<<` doesn't need to be qualified with `std::` in something like `std::cout << "\n";`, even though it's also in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to qualify them, at least in the general case.

To see why, create an array of 7 integers.  Use `sort` on the pointer to the first and one past the end: it will only work with `std::`.

```
 int foo[]={4,3,5,3,4,2,1};
 std::sort(&foo[0], &foo[8]); // std:: required to compile
```

However when the types in the arguments are from a `namespace`, functions in that `namespace` are searched when looking for overloads.  As you often use iterators which are often in `std` with `<algorithm>`s, this led you to believe that `std::` was not required in general: in reality you just got lucky!